# What is the Big-O of the function n^2/log(n)?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, big-o, notation, do-notation

the time complexity of an algorithm is given by n^2/log(n).
what is that in big O notation? Just n^2 or we keep the log?

Comment: Well `O(n^2)` _is_ an upper bound, but it is not the tightest upper bound.  The tightest upper bound is what you already have, `O(n^2/logn)`.

Comment: One of the big ohs to which `f(x)` is always belongs is `O(f(x))`.

Answer (score 0):

As `n^2 / (n^2/log(n))` goes to inifinity when `n` grows, so, `n^2/log(n) = o(n^2)` (little-oh). Therefore, `n^2/log(n)` is not equivalent to `n^2`.